# Failed call to AWS CLI service in order to get ELB Data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-cli

i am running Ubuntu Machine and i installed awscli using pip.

after this i configure the service with a user with full access to read monitor data.
My goal is to get a list of all my ELB at this Aws Account and go over all their instances.

this is the CLI command that i am trying to run :

```
 aws elb describe-load-balancers  --load-balancer-name "cpv" --region us-east-1b
```

i am trying a lot of diffrent combinations with the name , with - "" without "" i also configure the Region.

this is the reply i always get :

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='elasticloadbalancing.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

it seems the AWSCLI is trying to call to a default host and not to my ELB. 
i also tried the following for the name :

1. use the ELB - DNS_name and with http:// , and https://
2. Use DNS record that call to the ELB CNAME
3. Use with "" and without ""
4. Use the name with <> , [] around it

It seems that my awscli is set on using this default host

elasticloadbalancing.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com

Is there any way to configure this ?

The results of all those tries where all the same .. Fail

does anyone know how to make this work?

After Running this format :

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers   --load-balancer-names "my-VIP" --endpoint-url http://my-VIP.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com --debug
```

I got this debug out put :

```
    015-02-10 17:50:54,581 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI          version: aws-cli/1.7.5 Python/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-23-generic, botocore version: 0.86.0
2015-02-10 17:50:54,587 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,588 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,589 - MainThread - botocore.service - DEBUG - Creating service object for: elb
2015-02-10 17:50:54,832 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.elb: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,859 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: elb
2015-02-10 17:50:54,861 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.elb: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,862 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: elb
2015-02-10 17:50:54,863 - MainThread - botocore.service - DEBUG - Creating operation objects for: Service(elasticloadbalancing)
2015-02-10 17:50:54,920 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.elb: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,929 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([(u'load-balancer-names', ), (u'marker', ), (u'page-size', )])
2015-02-10 17:50:54,930 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,932 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,933 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,935 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.paginate - DEBUG - Modifying paging parameters for operation: Operation:DescribeLoadBalancers
2015-02-10 17:50:54,936 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,938 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler >
2015-02-10 17:50:54,939 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler >
2015-02-10 17:50:54,946 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event operation-args-parsed.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,951 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.elasticloadbalancing.describe-load-balancers.load-balancer-names: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,952 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.elasticloadbalancing.describe-load-balancers: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,953 - MainThread - awscli.argprocess - DEBUG - Detected structure: list-scalar
2015-02-10 17:50:54,953 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of [u'inj-VIP'] for parameter "load_balancer_names": [u'inj-VIP']
2015-02-10 17:50:54,954 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.elasticloadbalancing.describe-load-balancers.marker: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,955 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.elasticloadbalancing.describe-load-balancers.page-size: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,956 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.elasticloadbalancing.describe-load-balancers.cli-input-json: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,957 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.elasticloadbalancing.describe-load-balancers.starting-token: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,958 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.elasticloadbalancing.describe-load-balancers.max-items: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,959 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.elasticloadbalancing.describe-load-balancers.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:54,960 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler >
2015-02-10 17:50:54,961 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.elb.describe-load-balancers: calling handler >
2015-02-10 17:50:54,961 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2015-02-10 17:50:54,962 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2015-02-10 17:50:54,962 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2015-02-10 17:50:54,964 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2015-02-10 17:50:55,003 - MainThread - botocore.operation - DEBUG - Operation:DescribeLoadBalancers called with kwargs: {u'LoadBalancerNames': [u'inj-VIP']}
2015-02-10 17:50:55,008 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.elb: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:55,009 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: elb
2015-02-10 17:50:55,011 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for  (verify_ssl=False) with params: {'query_string': '', 'headers': {}, 'url_path': '/', 'body': {'Action': u'DescribeLoadBalancers', u'LoadBalancerNames.member.1': u'inj-VIP', 'Version': u'2012-06-01'}, 'method': u'POST'}
2015-02-10 17:50:55,013 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.elasticloadbalancing.DescribeLoadBalancers: calling handler 
2015-02-10 17:50:55,018 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2015-02-10 17:50:55,018 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

host:my-VIP.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-cli/1.7.5 Python/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-23-generic
x-amz-date:20150210T175055Z

host;user-agent;x-amz-date
c9392bdd24453ba27fb57ad4362df35f56eee79cf57d429cde9df313d2a5b18a
2015-02-10 17:50:55,019 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150210T175055Z
20150210/us-east-1b/elasticloadbalancing/aws4_request
856ff8a91801b14db9fbfdecb5ed94d0715a880ff56dca3d634ff22ac995ceaf
2015-02-10 17:50:55,025 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
5cdecf0ba02219076779d47dfa713c23eb1126f9975bf347f2205c0e5f223eca
2015-02-10 17:50:55,056 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: 
2015-02-10 17:50:55,061 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): my-VIP.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
2015-02-10 17:50:55,139 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 20
2015-02-10 17:50:55,146 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers:
{'connection': 'keep-alive',
 'content-length': '20',
 'content-type': 'text/html',
 'date': 'Tue, 10 Feb 2015 17:50:06 GMT',
 'server': 'nginx/1.1.19'}
2015-02-10 17:50:55,147 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
Web Analytics Server
2015-02-10 17:50:55,148 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 197, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 357, in __call__
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 492, in __call__
    self._operation_object, call_parameters, parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 594, in invoke
    parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 607, in _display_response
    formatter(operation, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/formatter.py", line 229, in __call__
    for _, page in response:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 70, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 390, in _make_request
    return self._operation.call(self._endpoint, **current_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/operation.py", line 164, in call
    response = endpoint.make_request(self.model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 105, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 143, in _send_request
    request, operation_model, attempts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 176, in _get_response
    operation_model.output_shape)),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 210, in parse
    parsed = self._do_parse(response, shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 399, in _do_parse
    root = self._parse_xml_string_to_dom(xml_contents)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 337, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
    parser.feed(xml_string)
ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
2015-02-10 17:50:55,159 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-names "your-elb-name"
```

where "your-elb-name" equals what you inputted into aws when you created it.  It can also be found in the first part of the public end point aws supplies

Comment: Thanks , i tried this and got the same result.. i think there is a problem with my default host

Comment: --endpoint-url http://my-vip.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com wiil cahnge the host detination now i get a new error at                                          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 197, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
syntax error: line 1,colum 0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your region is set to `us-east-1b`.  If you update this to `us-east-1` it should work.  You can do this via the `--region us-east-1`, setting the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1` env var, or adding "region = us-east-1" in `~/.aws/config`.

Comment: This is the Call i tried :                                                                                         aws elb describe-load-balancers  --no-verify-ssl --load-balancer-names "my-VIP" --endpoint-url https://my-VIP.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com --debug --region us-east-1         still the same result..

Comment: Don't include the `--endpoint-url` option.  The `--region` option is all you need to figure out the correct endpoint.

Comment: @Meta_data Then you should honor James' answer with [marking it as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).